# Transcendental extension of field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F(a)$ be a transcendental extension of the field $F$.  Given an element $b \in F(a)$ such that $b \notin F$, I would like to show that $F(a)$ is an algebraic extension of $F(b)$.

My idea of the proof is that if $b = \dfrac{f(a)}{g(a)}$, where $f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$.  Then $a $
is a root of

$$ bg(x)  - f(x)$$

which is a member of $F(b)[x]$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct under the assumption $b\notin F$, as this assumption ensures that your polynomial is not actually the zero polynomial.

If $f$ and $g$ are relatively prime ($a$ can be regarded as a variable because it is transcendental over $F$) and $f,g\neq 0$, at least one of which has positive degree, then the degree of $F(a)$ over $F(b)$ is $\max\{\deg(f),\deg(g)\}$. This is the degree of the polynomial you've written down, and it can be proved irreducible over $F(b)$, so it is a constant multiple of the minimal polynomial for $a$ over $F(b)$.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly I'm using the fact that $b \notin F$?

Comment: @user: If $b \in F$, then your idea becomes "$a$ is a root of the zero polynomial".

Comment: @user62898, As Hurkyl indicates, if $b\in F$, the polynomial you've written down wil be the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You need $bg(x) - f(x) \neq 0$. This is guaranteed if $g(x) \neq 0$ and $b \notin F$.